# Singleton as a data source for RecyclerView.Adapter

Tags: java, android

Can I have adapter that uses singleton instance as a data source? I am not going to have any static references to Views/Context, only plain data stored in singleton. Will there be any leaks or any downsides of such solution?

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    /* SINGLETON */
    private DataManager manager;

    public MyAdapter(DataManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create vh
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // bind vh
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return manager.itemsCount();
    }

}
```

DataManager is a singleton object that holds state/data in my Service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As it's a singleton, this means the class holds a reference to an instance of the class, and therefore the data will always be held in memory. This could cause your app to become less responsive if it is holding lots of resources.

In addition, if your app has a large footprint, Android's OS will be more likely to destroy your app in the event of low memory.

If possible (and it usually is), avoid singletons.

Comment: Data stored in this singleton is very lightweight (up to 10 list elements, typically 2 or 3).

Comment: Shouldn't cause any problems (unless the rest of your app is memory intensive). However why not just make it an object? Then once you navigate away from the layout with this RecyclerView, the data will be garbage collected & deleted from memory

Comment: I use this data in a service to make some api calls. I don't want it to be garbage collected ever unless user decides to remove it.

Comment: Ok. Persistent Storage options may also be worth looking into if you need to hold data - such as SharedPreferences, SQLite, or Realm

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases that you should use or not.

- If you'r getting data from Server and pass to Adapter then you should uses Singleton because it is a good idea for holding data instead of calling WebService every-time.
- If your data is static then you need not to hold the data in Singleton because it will slow down your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter referencing a singleton doesn't leak anything. Your data manager can leak memory if it's not implemented correctly.

Using singletons to store static data is just fine. You can just dispose the data when you're done using it.